# remove previous view controller from hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying skip one `ViewController` when I press back button from navigation bar.

When I go to next VC it needs to do this:

```
A -> B -> C
```

But when I want to go back from C, I want A `ViewController` to be presented:

```
C -> A
```

I managed to do that with next code:

```
    NSMutableArray *newControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:controllers];
    [newControllers removeObjectAtIndex:newControllers.count-2];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = newControllers;
```

Problem is navigation bar that is presented. When I get View from A `ViewController`, navigation bar from B ViewController is presented.

Is there any way that I can remove navigation bar items like I removed view controller from hierarchy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UIViewController *vcPop = nil;  
for (UIViewController *viewContrl in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
   if ([viewContrl class] == [YOUR POP VIEW CONTROLLER class]) {
       vcPop = (YOUR POP VIEW CONTROLLER  *)viewContrl;
       break;
 }
}
if(vcPop)
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:vcPop animated:YES];
```